# Why I can't install kohonen package R

Tags: r, package, cran

I'm studying machine/deep learning techniques in R and now studying the SOM I'm not abble to use it as it is giving the following error installing kohonen :

```
 install.packages("kohonen")

> Warning in install.packages :   unable to access index for repository
> https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:   cannot open destfile
> 'C:\Users\mt4tb\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi6JxwK\file1b885b813f09',
> reason 'No such file or directory' Installing package into
> ‘C:/Users/mt4tb/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> Warning in install.packages :   unable to access index for repository
> https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:   cannot open destfile
> 'C:\Users\mt4tb\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi6JxwK\file1b8822f6544f',
> reason 'No such file or directory' Warning in install.packages :  
> package ‘kohonen’ is not available for this version of R
> 
> A version of this package for your version of R might be available
> elsewhere, see the ideas at
> https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
> Warning in install.packages :   unable to access index for repository
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0:   cannot open
> destfile
> 'C:\Users\mt4tb\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi6JxwK\file1b886b5a60be',
> reason 'No such file or directory' Error in gzfile(file, mode) :
> cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In
> gzfile(file, mode) :   cannot open compressed file
> 'C:\Users\mt4tb\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi6JxwK/libloc_193_f8065c57.rds',
> probable reason 'No such file or directory' Error: no more error
> handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

By my understanding it seems that this package has no version for R 4.0 , am I right?

How do I solve it?

Thanks

P.S.

Trying to download and install it manually it returned me the following :

```
    > install.packages("C:/Users/mt4tb/Downloads/kohonen_3.0.10.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/mt4tb/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> * installing *source* package 'kohonen' ...
> ** package 'kohonen' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** using staged installation
> ** libs
> 
> *** arch - i386 Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found ERROR: compilation failed for package 'kohonen'
> * removing 'C:/Users/mt4tb/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/kohonen' Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
> ‘C:/Users/mt4tb/Downloads/kohonen_3.0.10.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit
> status Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection In
> addition: Warning message: In gzfile(file, mode) :   cannot open
> compressed file
> 'C:\Users\mt4tb\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi6JxwK/libloc_193_f8065c57.rds',
> probable reason 'No such file or directory' Error: no more error
> handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

Comment: Although the current version seems to have been built for Version 3.0.10 of R,  I just downloaded and installed `kohonen` on my copy of R 4.0.2.  I don't think that it is a version problem.

Comment: ok, gonna try install downloading it manually

Comment: it didn't worked

Comment: What error message did you get with your manual download?

Comment: Re failure to install from source: you appear to have forgotten to install the current version of Rtools. You will also need to install Rcpp before you can compile from source.

Comment: Man tanckhs a lot, after installing Rcpp it worked perfectly , thank you so much :)